# Detecting changes in a Javascript array using observe but not comparing to another array

Tags: javascript

I can detect changes in a javascript array by using Array.observe.

Like this:

```
Array.observe(myArray, function (changes) {
            // handle changes... in this case, we'll just log them 
            changes.forEach(function (change) {
                console.log(change.object);
             });
```

However I am not able to find an easy way of getting just the changed element (considering elements were added).

Is there a way to detect what was added without comparing this array to a copy of the original array ?

Comment: that info is in the event object passed to the callback (`change.index`, `change.removed`, etc). that said, you should not use `.observe()`; it's deprecated and will be removed.

Comment: It appears oldValue is not available in callback when array is modified via push. But you are correct, proxy is way to go, but this is for production.

Comment: i never recommended a proxy, which only runs in firefox. i said don't be so messy you need a log to figure out what changes were made...

Comment: Well, you are correct, a log isnt ideal, but this array keeps a log of pages dynamically loaded and I am somewhat tied to this approach for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accourding to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe) you can get this info from the data passed into the callback.

Also please pay attention that `Array.observe` **is obsolete** and consider using Proxy instead

Comment: Proxy is the opposite of obsolete: it doesn't work in many places yet... the real solution is to not make so many state mutations in so many places that you need an observer to keep track of them. backbone.js lets you code in a manner similiar to O.o and A.o if you like that sort of thing.

Comment: I have created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/awLga09e/
If I do an array.push, the expectation is getting the changed element only

It seems oldValue property is not available when array is modified via push ?

Comment: well, `push()` adds a new value, so there is no old value being replaced. i guess you can pretend that `chage.oldValue` is correct, since the old value was literally undefined...

Comment: So lets say I have an Array like this myarray = ['a','b','c']

Some method adds 'd' to myarray, is there no straight forward way to get just 'd' without comparing myarray to copy of itself ?